# How can I save a map in PostgreSQL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, leaflet, openstreetmap, react-leaflet

I'm currently working on an application for making geologic maps. I'm using Ruby on Rails for my back end, React for my front end, and Postgres for the database. I am using React Leaflet to display the maps (abstracts Leaflet.js to React components). I am getting the maps from OpenTopoMap. This application is non-commercial and I have checked their terms of use to make sure I am not in violation.

I want users to be able to view a map and be able to add points and draw polygons on it (I already know how to do this part). **Once they are done drawing on the map I want them to be able to save the map with whatever additions they have made. They should then be able to reopen it later and modify it.**

The only way I have found to save the map is as a .png, which means it can't be edited when it is reopened.

Saving only the points/polygons and re-rendering them when a user reopens the map is an acceptable solution as long as the correct area of the map is shown when it is reopened, but I am not sure how I would go about storing this data. A user can have many maps, so solutions that only work for a single instance of map will not work in this case.

I am aware that what I have described here just duplicates the functionality of many other mapping applications. Once this part is figured out I plan to add extensive functionality that is specific to making geological maps. I have not described that functionality here because it is not relevant to my current question.

**How can I save a map to PostgreSQL in a format that will allow it to be edited when reopened?**

Answer (score 2):

I use leaflet and leaflet.draw together to save the geoJSON from drawing polygons or dropping markers and save it to a field called coords in the database. There is a good example of it here: https://github.com/jeremygradisher/mapping-leaflet

It boils down to using leaflet.draw to draw the coordinates and then saving that data where you need it. Here is leaflet.draw: http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/docs/leaflet-draw-latest.html

Here I am using leaflet.draw to draw on the map and then I stringify the data and add it to a field to be saved in the database.

```
<script>
// Initialize the FeatureGroup to store editable layers
var drawnItems = new L.FeatureGroup();
map.addLayer(drawnItems);


// Initialize and alter the draw control and pass it the FeatureGroup of editable layers
var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
    draw: {
        //These options make up the root object that is used when initializing the Leaflet.draw control.
        position: 'topleft',
        polygon: {
            allowIntersection: false,
            drawError: {color: '#00dd00', timeout: 1000
            },
            shapeOptions: {color: '#00dd00', weight: 1}, showArea: true},
        polyline:  false,
        rectangle:  {shapeOptions: {color: '#00dd00',weight: 1}},circle: false},
    edit: {featureGroup: drawnItems}
});
map.addControl(drawControl);


//draw:created - Triggered when a new vector or marker has been created.
map.on('draw:created', function (e) {
    var type = e.layerType,
        layer = e.layer;

    var shape = layer.toGeoJSON();
var shape_for_db = JSON.stringify(shape);

    drawnItems.addLayer(layer);
    //trying some things here

    //enter in field to save to the database
    document.getElementById('area_coords').value = shape_for_db;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of reinventing the wheel with some JSON column monstrosity look into PostGIS. Its an extension for Postgres that adds geospatial data types like points, lines and polygons. It also lets you write geospatial database queries like for example testing if a point is in a polygon or proximity searches.

For rails the [the activerecord-postgis-adapter gem](https://github.com/rgeo/activerecord-postgis-adapter#upgrading-an-existing-database) adds these database types:

- `:geometry` -- Any geometric type
- `:st_point` -- Point data
- `:line_string` -- LineString data
- `:st_polygon` -- Polygon data
- `:geometry_collection` -- Any collection type
- `:multi_point` -- A collection of Points
- `:multi_line_string` -- A collection of LineStrings
- `:multi_polygon` -- A collection of Polygons

This provides the building blocks to create models with geospatial attributes. Its not a magic wand that will let you stuff a map with doodles into Postgres and get something editable out and will require a significant effort in both research and implementation.

Comment: I've used this in an application that used a geofence to notify users when they got near a mapped out polygon. Works really well

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you want to save complicated objects to the database. An user can draw lines on the map and can draw polygons and etc. Maybe using jsonb object for this problem can be your solution. Basically it's saving a JSON formatted field to database.

An example jsonb object can be like this.

```
{
  "data": {
    "type": "user_map",
    "attributes": {
      "user_id": "1",
      "drawings": {
        "points": [],
        "lines": {},
        "polygons": {}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can both keep these information on user or on separate model with using `has_many :maps` on user model.

Links that can help you:

[Example 1](https://www.compose.com/articles/faster-operations-with-the-jsonb-data-type-in-postgresql/)

[Example 2](https://rollout.io/blog/unleash-the-power-of-storing-json-in-postgres/)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not to think in terms of map (the rendering of spatial data) but in terms of data (a point/line/polygon with attributes). You would save each user data in tables, maybe have another map_config table that holds the map bounding box, name etc.

In you app, once you have authenticated the user, you give access to its map configurations (let him select the one to be shown) and associated data. You then display the map either using the raw vector data directly in Leaflet, Open Layers (or else), or you can pipe it through a geo server (Geoserver, Mapserver etc) for serving it as wms images, or wfs editable vector data. You zoom or restrict the displayed area to the one saved in the map configuration.